# How append query string while loading chunk files?

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

Similar to the issue reported [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2329):

> How can append query string to chunk files request when I use
>   require.ensure ?

But what if I have to send some custom parameters that are known only when I call `require.ensure`? For example an identification key that authorize the user HTTP GET request for the given chunk on the server-side?

Answer (score 0):

// https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11816#issuecomment-716402552

```
declare var __webpack_get_script_filename__: any;
const oldFn = __webpack_get_script_filename__;

__webpack_get_script_filename__ = (chunkId) => {
  const filename = oldFn(chunkId);
  return filename + `?v=${environment.timestamp}`;
};
```

go enjoy, do you love me ?